# how to get the selected date in jquery

Tags: jquery, calendar

i have followed

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Display inline</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

Date: <div id="datepicker"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/fgMc3/1/) to get calendar and got the calendar to be displayed on the page always.

Now i want to get the date selected and pass it to other function to process.

How to do this.

Best Rgards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this..

```
var selecteddate=  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
alert(selecteddate);
```

[here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) is the documentation

**updated**

use `onselect`, if you need it on click.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  onSelect: function(date) {
    alert(date);
    //do your processing here
  }
 });
```

Comment: updated my answer if u need the selected date whenever the date is selected.... else u can use `getDate` anywhere in your codes.. after the datepicker is inialtlized

Answer (score 2):

Use `onSelect` method which is called when date is selected and gets date as text

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date) {
      alert(date);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

onSelect

```
    $("#expirationDate").datepicker({
        buttonImage: '../Images/calendar.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: 'both',
        onSelect: function () {
            getValidTillDateValue(this);
        }
    });

  function getValidTillDateValue(ele) {
            return $(ele).val();
        }
```

If you want the Date value later say on form submit you want to check the value

```
valuePublishDate = $("#customerPublishingDate").datepicker("getDate");
```