# How can I get the values from the selected jquery datepicker inputs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" id="datepicker2">  
<input type="text" id="datepicker3">  

<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker, #datepicker2, #datepicker3" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0, maxDate: "+6M"});
});

var date = $( "#datepicker2" ).val();

</script>
```

I'm trying to get the value of the selected date with val(); but I always get "undefined"
The datepicker is working fine but I don't know how to get the values.

Comment: duplicates : [here][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288497/jquery-datepicker-get-selected-date] and [here][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986071/how-to-get-value-of-selected-date-with-jquery-datepicker] ... and [here][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154964/how-to-get-the-selected-date-in-jquery]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the [Doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) :

### ***getDate()***

**Returns:** *Date*

*Returns the current date for the datepicker or null if no date has been selected.*

- This method does not accept any arguments.

**Code examples:**

*Invoke the getDate method and store the value in a variable:*

```
var currentDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
```

Comment: Thanks brett for your quick reply.
But the thing is if I use that code the jquery-ui-datepicker stops working...
I have an ´<input type="text" id="datepicker">´ and when I choose the date, I want to later get the value I chose..
Have any ideia how to?
Again.. Thank you

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for this code to cause the datepicker to stop working. This is a tested feature that has been a part of this datepicker since it was created.. sounds like there is a deeper issue

Comment: The above code will return a date object representing the date selected, or null if no date has been selected

Comment: @pacafs see my updated answer. It shows how to get the value and store it for use later

Comment: DONE ;) Manny thanks my friend @BrettWeber

Comment: :) You are welcome. I hope your project success